# "Ci" e "ne" con "capire"

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, particles

Entrambe le versioni sono corrette?

> - Sei bravo in matematica? No, non *ci* capisco niente.
> - Sei bravo in matematica? No, non *ne* capisco niente.

Una è migliore dell'altra?

Comment: Interessante domanda. In catalano (una delle mie lingue) direi "no hi entenc gens" ("hi" è l'equivalente catalano della particella "ci" e l'avverbio "gens" si può tradurre come  "niente" o "nulla"). So che in italiano si dice invece "non me ne intendo". Con "capire qualcosa" al posto di "intendersi di qualcosa" la mia intuizione mi dice che è "non ci capisco niente" perché è appunto "in matematica" quello che stai chiedendo nella domanda "Sei bravo in matematica?"

Comment: Come curiosità, aggiungo che l'avverbio catalano *gens* equivale al francese *point*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mio avviso, nell'esempio riportato sono entrambe versioni corrette, dal significato sostanzialmente uguale ma con una "sfumatura" differente:

- *non **ci** capisco niente* può essere parafrasato con *non capisco niente **in un determinato/a ambito/situazione***
- *non **ne** capisco niente* può essere parafrasato con *non capisco niente **di un determinato argomento/oggetto***

Più in generale, direi che una differenza c'è: *non **ci** capisco niente* può essere usato anche da solo, come esclamazione, sottointendendo la situazione o l'ambito in cui ci si trova in quel momento ("Che confusione! Non ci capisco niente!"), mentre *non **ne** capisco niente* è sempre accompagnato da una frase o complemento che specifica a cosa si riferisca quel "ne" ("Non *ne* capisco niente, *di fisica quantistica*", "Ti piace *il jazz*? Non *ne* capisco niente").

Comment: @charo nella frase "non ci capisco più niente", il complemento oggetto di capire è "niente", non "ci"; "ci" fa riferimento all'ambito o alla situazione in cui ci si trova quindi "non *ci* capisco più niente" equivale a "non capisco più niente *in questa situazione*". Analogamente, "non ci capisco niente di matematica" equivale a dire "non capisco niente nell'ambito della matematica".

Comment: Beh, @secan, quello che succede è che, quando si usa *ne*, si sostituisce il **genitivo partitivo del complemento oggetto**: "Non capisco niente di tutto quello che costituisce la matematica" --> "Non ne capisco niente". Adesso ho capito completamente la questione e ho aggiunto una risposta su come la vedo io. Grazie!

Comment: Ecco come la vedo io (ma potrei essere sbagliata per influenza del catalano, la mia lingua, in cui strutture simili si comportano nel modo che sto per esporre): come avevo detto prima, nella frase "Non ci capisco (più) niente", "ci" è sicuramente pronome, mentre "niente" è avverbio (???) (punto 3 di https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/niente): quindi ***ci*  non è complemento oggetto** (???) della frase:  infatti, *capire* in questa frase non ha complemento oggetto (???). Non sono completamente sicura delle due ultime affermazioni che ho appena fatto, perciò ho messo i segni di interrogazione.

Comment: Appena avrò un po' di tempo libero, posterò una nuova domanda per chiedere su questi miei dubbi.

Answer (score 3):

Secondo il punto 4 della voce  [voce *ci* del vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ci1), la particella *ci* ha funzione di pronome dimostrativo in questo tipo di costrutti:

> 4. Con funzione di pron. dimostrativo, riferito a cosa, equivale a *ciò*, *quello*, preceduto da preposizione: «di ciò»: *ci avrei molto piacere*; «a ciò»: *non ci credo; non ci posso far nulla*; «su ciò»: *ci puoi contare*; «da ciò»: *quanto conti di guadagnarci?*; e spec., conservando ancora il suo valore fondamentale, «in ciò»: *non ci capisco nulla*; [...]".

Quindi, dovresti dire

> No, non *ci* capisco niente,

se vuoi esprimere "non capisco niente in tutto quello che fa riferimento alla matematica, che ha a che vedere con la matematica" come risposta alla domanda "Sei bravo *in* matematica?".

Tuttavia, nella [voce *ne* del vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ne1) si legge

> Con valore più chiaramente pronominale, di ciò, di questo, di quello, in funzione di complementi diversi: *non ne vedo la necessità*; *ne parlerò ai nostri soci*; *non saprei cosa farne*; *che cosa vuoi che ne faccia?*; *cercherò di farne a meno*

e anche

> assai frequente in luogo di un genitivo partitivo: *mi piacciono questi dolci, vorrei prenderne ancora*; *non ce ne sono più*; *non ne vedo altre*

Quindi, dovresti dire

> No, non *ne* capisco niente

se quello che vuoi esprimere è "non capisco niente di tutto ciò che a che vedere con la matematica, di tutto quello che costituisce la matematica". Cioè, *ne* sostituisce un genitivo partitivo, come nell'esempio "non ce ne sono più".

Potresti usare anche un costrutto in cui *ne* ha valore genitivo partitivo dicendo, per esempio,

> Ne capisco soltanto quello che ho imparato alla scuola elementare.

E, come ha menzionato @DaG nel suo commento, la particella *ne* si può anche usare con il verbo *capire* in espressioni come

> non *ne* capisco il senso / il motivo / l'urgenza

e simili.

Se invece vuoi usare il verbo intransitivo pronominale [*intendersi*](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/intendere), allora dovresti usare la particella "ne":

> Come intr. pron., *intendersi* (*di qualche cosa*), avere cognizione diretta, esperienza e competenza in una disciplina, una tecnica, un’arte, una professione, ecc.: *intendersi di letteratura, di storia, di pittura, di musica, di politica, di motori, di stoffe*; *intendersi poco, molto*; *di codeste cose non m’intendo affatto*; *lascia fare a me che me n’intendo*.

Cioè, potresti dire

> Sei bravo in matematica? No, non me *ne* intendo affatto

per esprimere "non m'intendo affatto di matematica".

Comment: “Non ne capisco” non è particolarmente arcaico e neppure rarissimo. Oltre che usato con “niente/nulla/molto”, si può dire per esempio “non ne capisco il senso / il motivo / l'urgenza” e simili.

Comment: Grazie mille, @DaG: risposta modificata :)

Comment: Mi sembra che ora vada benone.

Comment: Ebbene, @DaG, come diceva Dante: *Nasce per quello, a guisa di rampollo, / a piè del vero il dubbio; ed è natura/ ch’al sommo pinge noi di collo in collo* (*Paradiso* IV, 130-133). Grazie una volta in più!

Comment: @DaG: Adesso mi sembra di aver capito meglio la questione. Secondo me, la differenza fondamentale è che "niente" (o "nulla") nella frase "non ci capisco niente" è avverbio ("niente" è avverbio e "ci" è pronome, vedi il mio ultimo commento sotto la domanda), mentre nella frase "non ne capisco niente" è pronome. È questo precisamente quello che difficoltava la mia comprensione perché in catalano abbiamo due termini diversi per "niente" avverbio e per "niente" pronome: "gens" e "res", rispettivamente. (Segue)

Comment: (Cont.) È anche questa la ragione per cui possiamo perfettamente dire "Su questa questione non posso dire la mia perché non ci capisco", mentre  "Su come si potrebbe concludere... non ***ne*** capisco niente" (l'esempio arcaico che menzionavo prima) non si usa nell'italiano contemporaneo.

Comment: @DaG: Trovo molto curioso che questo uso intransitivo di "capire" (ad esempio, *non posso dire la mia opinione perché non **ci** capisco*) non sia menzionato sul Treccani: questo è anche un aspetto che ha difficoltato molto la mia comprensione della questione.

Comment: Succede anche che, nella mia lingua, "no n'entenc res" è grammaticalmente corretto, ma non è idiomatico.

Comment: @DaG: Forse questo problema si dovrebbe chiarire ponendo una nuova domanda. Magari l'italiano funziona in modo diverso dal catalano per quanto riguarda queste strutture con "niente" o "nulla" (che corrispondono approssimativamente al pronome "res" e all'avverbio "gens" in catalano) e i clitici "ne" ("en" in catalano) e "ci" ("hi" in catalano). Come non italiana, si tratta di una questione molto difficile per me.